# iOS render image in context not working as expected in landscape orientation

Tags: ios, render, cglayer, uigraphicscontext

The code below seems to work well to render an image from a view at retina resolution. The problem is it does not seem to work while my device is in landscape orientation. It returns an image rotated 90 degrees.

Do I need to add options for image or context orientation?

```
    CGSize panelRect = CGSizeMake(selectedPanelView.frame.size.width, selectedPanelView.frame.size.height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(panelRect, 1, 2);

    [[selectedPanelView layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be fixed by using: `UIImage imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:` as below.

```
UIImage *renderedImageWithOrientation = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:renderedImage.CGImage scale:1 orientation:0];
```

I run this after rendering the image, then I add the image to the imageView.